# How to get email address based on inbox click in outlook addin?

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

[image]I am creating outlook addin using visual studio 2015.

I have config two email address in outlook 2016.now when I click on specific inbox I want email address of the user who belongs to the inbox.

Comment: Just an aside, which email address? A user can have more than one assigned to them, even for a single specific inbox.

Comment: @Rob: Please see above image.when i click on tsstest111@gmail.com's inbox i want tsstest111@gmail.com same thing for the second account.

Comment: then use the name of the folder.. if you can guarantee the folder structure is like that for all

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to figure out the owner of a particular store? Keep in mind that some stores (e.g. PST) do not have an intrinsic user associated with them - it could be a standalone PST or a PST with multiple POP3/SMTP accounts delivering to that store.

You can loop through the `Application.Session.Accounts` collection and check the `Account.DeliveryStore` property (compare the store entry ids using `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`).